# How do you add a core twig extension in plugins using addTwigExtension()?

Tags: templating, plugins

Is it possible to activate the following Twig extension from within a craft plugin:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/date.html

Comment: If the `time_diff` filter is all you need, then maybe it's worth looking into this Craft plugin with similar functionality: ["Time Ago In Words"](https://github.com/blue-mantis/BM-Time-Ago-In-Words).

Comment: How did I miss that?! Perfect, I will need to extend functionality a tad as I also need to return the actual difference values in years, months and days too.

Answer (score 1):

The Twig extension package is not included with your Craft install. So you need to [download](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig-extensions) it and add it to your Craft plugin manually.