# How to install a Twig extension

Tags: templating

How do install a Twig extension in Craft? Not write my own extension, but install an extension that exists. I want to install the extensions extension. There are a number of posts that describe how to write your own extension, but I can't see how to just install one. The Twig docs says add this: `$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_Array());` but obviously I don't want to edit core Craft.

I found this - [How do you add a core twig extension in plugins using addTwigExtension()?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8223/how-do-you-add-a-core-twig-extension-in-plugins-using-addtwigextension), but the responses just convince the poster that he doesn't need to use that extension. What if he wanted to use it? How do you install it?

Answer (score 1):

The [BreakAndContinue](https://github.com/marionnewlevant/craft-mnbreakandcontinue) plugin is an example of a plugin that adds a simple twig extension. I would start with that, and modify it to add the extensions extension (I assume that is this: https://github.com/twigphp/Twig-extensions ?) You might need to tweak the Twig PHP to get files to load etc., but not core Craft, since this will be a plugin.

Comment: ok cool I'll give it a go. Yeah twig-extensions is the one I want. I just need to randomise an array so shuffle looks good. I could easily write my own code to do it, but I thought I'd use this as an exercise to see how to add extensions

Comment: yep it worked, probably more trouble than it was worth just get a wrapper on the php shuffle function, but now I know how to do it! thanks